# Building first Android App, trying to connect to a URL on load and fetch data

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn how to program using Android, and I am trying to make a WEB API call from within the base app that the SDK starts with. I simply copied some code, but I do not detect any connection occuring on my web server. Any ideas?

```
package com.example.androidhello;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

URL url;{
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.15/insertrecord.php");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
            System.out.print(current);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

When I connect from the browser to the URL, my web server enters a record into mysql so I know the URL was visited, and I echo out a return. the next thing I want to do is store the return and later JSON it, but for now I do not see a call. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this: _http://192.168.1.15/insertrecord.php_ open in the device (or an emulator for that matter) browser? The IP suggests you are hosting it locally at the moment. Also, do you have the permission to use Internet defined in the Manifest? This one: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Oh wait! Also move the `try.... catch` block inside the `oncreate()` right after the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Why are you running the network code in an instance initializer block?  That's really not good Java code, for any platform (Android, or otherwise).

Comment: Thanks for the help IceMAN I will try the suggestions. Also Nate, I am sure that is not where it goes, but I figured I should get it to work and then move it to a class of its own that I can call when I need it. I know this isn't a good way to design a program and I am just trying to learn for my own benefit, coming in as a web developer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the HTTP request through either an `AsyncTask`, or `IntentService`.

Android does not allow you to do long running operation on the main UI thread to avoid sluggish UI rendering feeling.